# Photoshop Layer Effects similar functionality with GIMP?

Tags: gimp

In photoshop there is a button on bottom of the layers panel,looking similar to this "(ƒ<sub>x</sub>)" . How can I achieve similar effect on layers within GIMP?

Comment: you dont. Gimp is not the in same tool category as photoshop.

Comment: Ok, is there anything to change/edit blending modes with parameter in gimp?

Comment: No, there isn't. We need to get to GIMP 3.2 to get that: https://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Roadmap#GIMP_3.2

Comment: These are caller Layer Effects in Photoshop. GIMP doesn't have them by default, however there is a layer effects plugin (layerfx.py) which will get you some way towards similar functionality. You'll have to search using google to find it. Also note that it's not non-destructive like Photoshop's layer effects.

Comment: @BillyKerr That is a perfect answer to the question, why don't you post it as such? :)

Comment: @vincent - to be honest, this is an old question and I'm not entirely sure if the layerfx.py plugin will still work with the latest version of GIMP. The plugin is very old now and hasn't been updated since 2012.  Might be better to look for other plugins for applying effects, such as G'MIC.

Comment: @BillyKerr Ah, good reason. Thanks for the help, anyway :)